# how to upload user avatar in django through angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I want to give the registration is possible the user to download your picture.
I have custom user model:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self,username, email, password):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email непременно должен быть указан')

        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            email=UserManager.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username,email, password):
        user = self.create_user(username, email, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_admin = True

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class ExtUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(
        'Электронная почта',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        blank=True
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        'Аватар',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        upload_to="user/avatar"
    )
    firstname = models.CharField(
        'Фамилия',
        max_length=40,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=30,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(
                r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                _('Enter a valid username. This value may contain only '
                  'letters, numbers ' 'and @/./+/-/_ characters.')
            ),
        ],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    lastname = models.CharField(
        'Имя',
        max_length=40,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    middlename = models.CharField(
        'Отчество',
        max_length=40,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(
        'Дата рождения',
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    register_date = models.DateField(
        'Дата регистрации',
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        'Активен',
        default=True
    )
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(
        'Суперпользователь',
        default=False
    )
    balance = models.DecimalField(
        'Деньги пользователя',
        default=0.00,
        decimal_places = 2,
        max_digits = 200
    )

    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(Season, blank=True)

    #
    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email


    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пользователь'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'
```

register API:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def register(request):
    VALID_USER_FIELDS = [f.name for f in get_user_model()._meta.fields]
    DEFAULTS = {
        # you can define any defaults that you would like for the user, here
    }
    serialized = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serialized.is_valid():
        user_data = {field: data for (field, data) in request.data.items() if field in VALID_USER_FIELDS}
        user_data.update(DEFAULTS)
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            **user_data
        )
        return Response(UserSerializer(instance=user).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

register function in JS controller:

```
$scope.register = function(email, password, username, avatar) {
    return $http.post('/api/v1/auth/register/', {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        email: email,
        'avatar':avatar
    }).success(function(data, status) {
        return $scope.login(username, password)
        window.location = '/'
    })

}
```

HTML-form:

```
  <form role="form" ng-submit="register(email,password,username, avatar)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="register__email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="register__email" ng-model="email" placeholder="email@email.com" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="register__username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="register__username" ng-model="username" placeholder="Bon Jovi" />
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="register__username">Avatar</label>
           <input name="pic" type="file" id="pic" accept="image/*">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="register__password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="register__password" ng-model="password" placeholder='12345' />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

What do I need to do in terms of api , and javascript, to make it work ?

Comment: Have you set Content Type to multipart-form-data ? What error do you get ?

Comment: i have no ideas how to do it, i need a step by step instruction :)